# emberjs - refactor custom link-to to htmlbars

Tags: ember.js

Previously I had my own custom `link-to` helper that I blogged about [here](http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2014/01/24/custom-link-to-refactor/).

With handlebars I could pass arguments that would cause a re-render if the value changed, for example if I am binding to model that has `isLoaded=false`, then the `LinkView` view would re-render when `isLoaded=true` or the value changed from undefined to its value.

Below is my old handlebars custom link-to helper

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('resource-link-to', function(path, options) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var resource = this.get(path);
  var resourceRoute = resource.humanize();

  if (!options.fn) {
    options.types = ['STRING', 'STRING', 'ID'];
    options.contexts = [this, this, this];
    args.unshift(path);
    args.unshift(resourceRoute);
    args.unshift(resource.get('displayName'));
  } else {
    options.types = ['STRING', 'ID'];
    options.contexts = [this, this];
    args.unshift(path);
    args.unshift(resourceRoute);
  }
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers['link-to'].apply(this, args);
});
```

The `ID` marker in this line meant it was a binding:

```
options.types = ['STRING', 'STRING', 'ID'];
```

I am trying to replicate this in htmlbars in ember `1.13.11` and I have extendted the `LinkComponent` and overriden `willRender` like this:

```
export default LinkComponent.extend({
  willRender() {
    // FIXME: allow for css classes and query params
    Ember.assert('you must specify a resource', this.attrs.resource);

    const resource = this.attrs.resource;

    let resourceRoute = resource.value.humanize();

    if(typeToLinks[resourceRoute]) {
      resourceRoute = typeToLinks[resourceRoute];
    }

    this.set('attrs', {
      params: [resource.value.get('displayName'), resourceRoute, resource],
      view: this.parentView,
      hasBlock: false,
      escaped: true
    });

    this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

I then call it like this:

```
{{resource-linkto resource=activity.reference}}
```

The problem is that the `resource` might be in an `isLoaded=false` state as it is partially resolved.

How can I trigger a re-render when the value is resolved like I used to do in handlebars?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I cannot really see how you are leveraging the `isLoaded` flag in your first example. Please add a comment on the following solution to correct me if I misunderstood you in any way.

> How can I trigger a re-render when the value is resolved like I used to do in handlebars?

This would probably be the easiest to solve by using an observer on the `isLoaded` property of the `resource` and call `rerender()` when the property changes:

```
export default LinkComponent.extend({

  // isLoaded: Ember.computed.alias('resource.isLoaded') // OR you can create this alias and use `isLoaded` instead of `resource.isLoaded` throughout your code

  // rerender the component when the resource isLoaded becomes true
  onResourceLoaded: Ember.observer('resource.isLoaded', function() {
    if(this.get('resource.isLoaded')) {
      this.rerender();
    }
  }

  willRender() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

---

**NOTE**

The code within `willRender` will be called again after calling `rerender()`.

If you need that code to execute only once, you can use the following [component hooks](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_component-lifecycle-hooks) instead of `willRender`:

- `didInsertElement` if you want code to run the first time the element is inserted in the DOM.
- `didInitAttrs` if you want code to run after a component was created and passed `attrs` are guaranteed to be present.